# Which test do I use; need to compare tests with one another pre and post intervention

Tags: correlation, anova

I am writing a thesis on the validity of balance training tests.
I need to compare the tests and see if they correlate with one another in testing balance in the elderly.
There's a control and intervention group, and 9 different balance tests were used to test each subject. Need to see if the tests correlate with one another or not.

Comment: perhaps you can run cronbach's $\alpha$ on each group? But I wonder what your final intent is, as this is not comparing the control vs intervention group.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this written in this paper, http://econ.duke.edu/uploads/media_items/lee-dongkeun-financial-derivatives.original.pdf, which used Ljung–Box test which perhaps you could look into.